# FedEx Error code 8336: "Service is not allowed" when using international shipments in SOAP WebService

Tags: web-services, soap, fedex

I would like to use FedEx SOAP Web Service to create international shipments (`<ns1:ServiceType>INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY</ns1:ServiceType>`). After sending my SOAP message instead of getting SUCCESS message, I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ShipmentReply xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v21">
      <HighestSeverity>ERROR</HighestSeverity>
      <Notifications>
        <Severity>ERROR</Severity>
        <Source>ship</Source>
        <Code>8336</Code>
        <Message>Service is not allowed.</Message>
        <LocalizedMessage>Service is not allowed.</LocalizedMessage>
      </Notifications>
      <TransactionDetail>
        <CustomerTransactionId>000006634</CustomerTransactionId>
      </TransactionDetail>
      <Version>
        <ServiceId>ship</ServiceId>
        <Major>21</Major>
        <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
        <Minor>0</Minor>
      </Version>
    </ShipmentReply>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm sending:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v21">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ValidateShipmentRequest>
          <ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <ns1:ParentCredential>
              <ns1:Key>XXX</ns1:Key>
              <ns1:Password>XXX</ns1:Password>
            </ns1:ParentCredential>
            <ns1:UserCredential>
              <ns1:Key>*********</ns1:Key>
              <ns1:Password>*********</ns1:Password>
            </ns1:UserCredential>
          </ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
          <ns1:ClientDetail>
            <ns1:AccountNumber>*********</ns1:AccountNumber>
            <ns1:MeterNumber>>*********</</ns1:MeterNumber>
          </ns1:ClientDetail>
          <ns1:TransactionDetail>
            <ns1:CustomerTransactionId>000006634</ns1:CustomerTransactionId>
          </ns1:TransactionDetail>
          <ns1:Version>
            <ns1:ServiceId>ship</ns1:ServiceId>
            <ns1:Major>21</ns1:Major>
            <ns1:Intermediate>0</ns1:Intermediate>
            <ns1:Minor>0</ns1:Minor>
          </ns1:Version>
          <ns1:RequestedShipment>
            <ns1:ShipTimestamp>2018-07-10T13:15:38+00:00</ns1:ShipTimestamp>
            <ns1:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</ns1:DropoffType>
            <ns1:ServiceType>INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY</ns1:ServiceType>
            <ns1:PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</ns1:PackagingType>
            <ns1:TotalWeight>
              <ns1:Units>KG</ns1:Units>
              <ns1:Value>25</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:TotalWeight>
            <ns1:Shipper>
              <ns1:Contact>
                <ns1:PersonName>>*********</</ns1:PersonName>
                <ns1:CompanyName>>*********</</ns1:CompanyName>
                <ns1:PhoneNumber>>*********</</ns1:PhoneNumber>
              </ns1:Contact>
              <ns1:Address>
                <ns1:StreetLines>>*********</</ns1:StreetLines>
                <ns1:City>>*********</</ns1:City>
                <ns1:StateOrProvinceCode/>
                <ns1:PostalCode>>*********</</ns1:PostalCode>
                <ns1:CountryCode>GB</ns1:CountryCode>
              </ns1:Address>
            </ns1:Shipper>
            <ns1:Recipient>
              <ns1:Contact>
                <ns1:PersonName>Test Test</ns1:PersonName>
                <ns1:CompanyName/>
                <ns1:PhoneNumber>222222222</ns1:PhoneNumber>
              </ns1:Contact>
              <ns1:Address>
                <ns1:StreetLines>Test</ns1:StreetLines>
                <ns1:City>Test</ns1:City>
                <ns1:StateOrProvinceCode/>
                <ns1:PostalCode>IV69AB</ns1:PostalCode>
                <ns1:CountryCode>GB</ns1:CountryCode>
                <ns1:Residential>false</ns1:Residential>
              </ns1:Address>
            </ns1:Recipient>
            <ns1:ShippingChargesPayment>
              <ns1:PaymentType>SENDER</ns1:PaymentType>
              <ns1:Payor>
                <ns1:ResponsibleParty>
                  <ns1:AccountNumber>700636402</ns1:AccountNumber>
                  <ns1:Address>
                    <ns1:CountryCode>GB</ns1:CountryCode>
                  </ns1:Address>
                </ns1:ResponsibleParty>
              </ns1:Payor>
            </ns1:ShippingChargesPayment>
            <ns1:CustomsClearanceDetail>
              <ns1:DutiesPayment>
                <ns1:PaymentType>SENDER</ns1:PaymentType>
                <ns1:Payor>
                  <ns1:ResponsibleParty>
                    <ns1:AccountNumber>700636402</ns1:AccountNumber>
                    <ns1:Address>
                      <ns1:CountryCode>GB</ns1:CountryCode>
                    </ns1:Address>
                  </ns1:ResponsibleParty>
                </ns1:Payor>
              </ns1:DutiesPayment>
              <ns1:DocumentContent>NON_DOCUMENTS</ns1:DocumentContent>
              <ns1:CustomsValue>
                <ns1:Currency>UKL</ns1:Currency>
                <ns1:Amount>35.99</ns1:Amount>
              </ns1:CustomsValue>
              <ns1:Commodities>
                <ns1:NumberOfPieces>1</ns1:NumberOfPieces>
                <ns1:Description>>*********</</ns1:Description>
                <ns1:CountryOfManufacture>GB</ns1:CountryOfManufacture>
                <ns1:Weight>
                  <ns1:Units>KG</ns1:Units>
                  <ns1:Value>25.0000</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Weight>
                <ns1:Quantity>1.0000</ns1:Quantity>
                <ns1:QuantityUnits>EA</ns1:QuantityUnits>
                <ns1:UnitPrice>
                  <ns1:Currency>UKL</ns1:Currency>
                  <ns1:Amount>29.9900</ns1:Amount>
                </ns1:UnitPrice>
                <ns1:CustomsValue>
                  <ns1:Currency>UKL</ns1:Currency>
                  <ns1:Amount>35.9900</ns1:Amount>
                </ns1:CustomsValue>
              </ns1:Commodities>
              <ns1:ExportDetail>
                <ns1:B13AFilingOption>NOT_REQUIRED</ns1:B13AFilingOption>
              </ns1:ExportDetail>
            </ns1:CustomsClearanceDetail>
            <ns1:LabelSpecification>
              <ns1:LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</ns1:LabelFormatType>
              <ns1:ImageType>PDF</ns1:ImageType>
              <ns1:LabelStockType>PAPER_4X6</ns1:LabelStockType>
            </ns1:LabelSpecification>
            <ns1:PackageCount>3</ns1:PackageCount>
            <ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems>
              <ns1:SequenceNumber>1</ns1:SequenceNumber>
              <ns1:GroupPackageCount>1</ns1:GroupPackageCount>
              <ns1:Weight>
                <ns1:Units>KG</ns1:Units>
                <ns1:Value>25</ns1:Value>
              </ns1:Weight>
              <ns1:Dimensions>
                <ns1:Length>20</ns1:Length>
                <ns1:Width>20</ns1:Width>
                <ns1:Height>10</ns1:Height>
                <ns1:Units>CM</ns1:Units>
              </ns1:Dimensions>
            </ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems>
          </ns1:RequestedShipment>
        </ns1:ValidateShipmentRequest>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Any ideas/help are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with Country of Receipment other than Country of Sender (GB - in my question) and it seems to work. (I changed aloso service type from INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY to INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY)

Comment: Yes, the problem I also was facing was because of the service type being `FedEx 2 Days` instead of `Internation priority`. Thank you for answering it.